# windows batch .bat automatic .m3u playlist creation / update

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, playlist, m3u

tired of manually updating my huge mp3/mp4 DB each time i add new files on my computer and/or smartphone, 
so i'm looking for some help to create a batch file that create/update all my playlists .m3u automatically.

2 batch files are required (1st is calling the 2nd) :

---

1st one is easy, i've almost got it ;-)

create_all_playlist.bat (no arguments required, customized file)

```
create_m3u.bat  misc-70-80.m3u            misc\70\ misc\80\
create_m3u.bat  misc-70-80-90.m3u         misc\70\ misc\80\ misc\90\
create_m3u.bat  misc-60-70-2000-2010.m3u  misc\60\ misc\70\ misc\2000\ misc\2010\
[...]
create_m3u.bat  albums-2010.m3u           albums\2010\
```

pretty easy huh?

---

I need your help to write the 2nd .bat, the dynamic one :

**create_m3u.bat *output-playlist-name.m3u folder-1 folder-2 [...] folder-n***

to play it easy, the output file.m3u should looks like this (note all are *relative path* and the search for *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg (whatever type i cutomize/hard-code) would be *recursive* into the designated folder)

(raw .m3u compatible with most android & PC player)

```
misc\2000s\Kelly Rowland - Work (Freemasons Arabic Mix).mp3
misc\2000s\Keri Hilson - Knock You Down ft Kanye West and Ne-Yo.mp3
misc\2000s\Kid Cudi vs Crookers - Day n Nite.mp3
misc\2000s\Korn - Inja.mp3
[...]
misc\2000s\Ladyhawke - My Delirium.mp3
```

---

At very best, only for the very best, let's say if someone is skilled enough to produce the full mp3/mp4 TAG reading and formating as following

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:227,A-Ha - Take On Me
misc\80s\A-Ha - Take On Me.mp3
#EXTINF:257,ACDC - Back in Black
misc\80s\ACDC - Back in Black.mp3
#EXTINF:311,Aerosmith & Run Dmc - Walk This Way
misc\80s\Aerosmith & Run Dmc - Walk This Way.mp3
[...]
#EXTINF:289,Alannah Myles - Black Velvet
misc\80s\Alannah Myles - Black Velvet.mp3
```

---

and thanks!!

for the raw m3u, beers are on me :-)

for the extended full m3u : beers and i'll cook the duck magret  ;-)

Comment: what is 227/257/311 for with the #EXTINF tag?

Comment: track time in seconds --
[link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3u)

Comment: You'd have to provide info about what you expect in each folder - Such as an `m3u` file in `every folder` under `c:\misc` with every `mp3` file in the file and `no other filetypes` and called `MyMusic.m3u`.  Adjust as neccessary.

Comment: not sure we understand each other there --foxidrive-- i need the batch to recursively search into the designated folder (passed as parameters) and look for *.mp3 *.m4a *.ogg (whatever file type) and produce 1 and only 1 playlist.m3u as designated as parameter. let me know if i'm not clear enough

Comment: So - how do you extract the run-time data?

Comment: 3 options @Magoo :  
**-1st you don't :** for the version 1.0 plain text, no need for that, just the file_name.mp3 is ok;  
**-2nd you don't :** even for the version 2.0 extended, time length is an option not a requirement... so you can simply skip it (#EXTINF:,ACDC[...]) or put any value i guess (put 0?)   
**-3rd you do :** version 2.0; for that you need to read the MP3/MP4/OGG tag to get the length, but it would be overkill and a hassle if too many file types are involved, i guess you need another meta-TAG reader as *get_MP3_TAG(in.file, out.length, out.title, out.artist, out.field [...])*

Comment: I faced similar task and here is my solution:
http://vitsoft.info/skimid3.htm#TalkingPlayer

Comment: děkuji @vitsoft!  for the version 1.0, i'll stick to the raw .bat -- let's say the version 2.0 will use your `skimid3.exe /s`, any .bat script proposal on how to plug it inside the existing @Magoo .bat script ?

Comment: last tuning... i have this output (absolute path) `\0-smartphone\SD card\0-music\misc-AAC\1980s\A-Ha - Take On Me.m4a` and the players (phone & PC in sync mirror that's why) would prefer (relative path) `misc-AAC\1980s\A-Ha - Take On Me.m4a` and i don't know how to tweak.... help @Magoo please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")



:: Need the start of the tree to scan
SET "rootdir=c:\sourcedir"
>"%tempfile%b" (ECHO(%rootdir%&ECHO(*)
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /o /L "*" "%tempfile%b"') DO SET /a len=%%a-1

SET "destfile=%~1"

:loop
SHIFT
SET nextdir=%~1
IF NOT DEFINED nextdir GOTO process
PUSHD "%rootdir%\%~1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg') DO >>"%tempfile%a" ECHO(%%~na:%%a
POPD 
GOTO loop

:process
>%destfile% ECHO(#EXTM3U
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('SORT "%tempfile%a"') DO (
 ECHO(#EXTINF:???,%%a
 SET "location=%%b"
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
 ECHO(!location:~%len%!
 endlocal
)
)>>%destfile%
DEL "%tempfile%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

I used `c:\sourcedir` as my starting directory. No parameter-validity checks are performed. You'd need to `CALL create_m3u.bat` from `create_all_playlist.bat` because the target executble is a batch file.

As for the missing data - hardest part is extracting information....

---

Edited to allow `!` in filenames and remove leading `\` from path

---

Revision: To permit absolute path

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")



:: Need the start of the tree to scan
SET "rootdir=c:\sourcedir"
>"%tempfile%b" (ECHO(%rootdir%&ECHO(*)
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /o /L "*" "%tempfile%b"') DO SET /a len=%%a-1

SET "destfile=%~1"

:loop
SHIFT
SET nextdir=%~1
IF NOT DEFINED nextdir GOTO process
IF %nextdir:~0,1%==\ (
 PUSHD "%~1"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg') DO >>"%tempfile%a" ECHO(%%~na:2:%%a
) else (
 PUSHD "%rootdir%\%~1"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg') DO >>"%tempfile%a" ECHO(%%~na:%len%:%%a
)
POPD 
GOTO loop

:process
>%destfile% ECHO(#EXTM3U
(
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=:" %%a IN ('SORT "%tempfile%a"') DO (
 ECHO(#EXTINF:???,%%a
 SET "location=%%c"
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  ECHO(!location:~%%b!
 endlocal
)
)>>%destfile%

del "%tempfile%*"

GOTO :EOF
```

Noting that "paths containing spaces must be in quotes"

Comment: man you're crafty!! you even added the _SORT_ you rock, tell me you blind wrote it, and i'll believe you can walk on water ;-)  -- so 99.8% good 1st pass! -- just 1 line to tweak : output is `\misc\60s\The_.mp3` and should be `misc\60s\The_.mp3`-- then i got issue with `!` in `files_names!.mp3` : it might get interpreted as signal/command for windows... but it is least concern i can banish `!` from files names, it is so uncommon... for the track length, if i can find a cmd-line lightweight exec maybe i'll plug it afterward, but having the track declare at 0 is ok, who cares how long is a song?

Comment: thanks, thanks, ands thanks @Magoo, all good on the 2nd pass!!! 
Confirmed working on win7 cmd, for win winamp and stock android player.
now, how/where can i put the full .zip source & a small read me for other users looking for the same automation? is there a windows batch repository for useful scripts somewhere on the net?  
if you want to add your contributor name on the script... be welcome!  
as for the beer and duck, it wasn't a joke, if you happen to be a neighbor near Nice in France, be my guest!

Comment: last tuning... i have this output (absolute path)
`\0-smartphone\SD card\0-music\misc-AAC\1980s\A-Ha - Take On Me.m4a`
and the players (phone & PC in sync mirror that's why) would prefer (relative path) `misc-AAC\1980s\A-Ha - Take On Me.m4a` and i don't know how to tweak.... help @Magoo please!!