# Constant string in dynamic batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, playlist, m3u

I have a batch script (-> [windows batch .bat automatic .m3u playlist creation / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401214/windows-batch-bat-automatic-m3u-playlist-creation-update) ) to automatically generate playlists. These playlists are saved in a subfolder of the rootdir (see code).
So the problem is, that the subfolder is not taken into account in the playlist, so the music files cannot be found. I get

```
#EXTINF:???,The Realm Of Orzamar
Dragon Age Origins\The Realm Of Orzamar.mp3
```

I need

```
#EXTINF:???,The Realm Of Orzamar
../Dragon Age Origins\The Realm Of Orzamar.mp3
```

And with something like

```
SET "location='.../' + %%c"
```

I get

```
#EXTINF:???,The Realm Of Orzamar
:\music\Dragon Age Origins\The Realm Of Orzamar.mp3
```

How can I put this `.../` string into `SET "location=%%c"` so it won't be converted to `music\` . An absolut path is not quite a solution since the filestructure is placed on a portable drive and should work independant and out of the folder root, so for use on Android devices and on any other device with different absolut full paths.
I am unexperienced with batch, just did some very basic stuff so far, I don't really understand this script since I don't know batch syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
CHCP 1252
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")



:: Need the start of the tree to scan
SET "rootdir=H:\music"
>"%tempfile%b" (ECHO(%rootdir%&ECHO(*)
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /o /L "*" "%tempfile%b"') DO SET /a len=%%a-1

SET "destfile=%~1"

:loop
SHIFT
SET nextdir=%~1
IF NOT DEFINED nextdir GOTO process
IF %nextdir:~0,1%==\ (
 PUSHD "%~1"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg *.m4a *.wma *.flac *.wav') DO >>"%tempfile%a" ECHO(%%~na:2:%%a
) else (
 PUSHD "%rootdir%\%~1"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.mp4 *.ogg *.m4a *.wma *.flac *.wav') DO >>"%tempfile%a" ECHO(%%~na:%len%:%%a
)
POPD 
GOTO loop

:process
>%destfile% ECHO(#EXTM3U
(
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=:" %%a IN ('SORT "%tempfile%a"') DO (
 ECHO(#EXTINF:???,%%a
 SET "location=%%c"
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  ECHO(!location:~%%b!
 endlocal
)
)>>%destfile%

 del "%tempfile%*"


GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Do not use forward slashes as path separators since the back-slash is standard in Windows!

Comment: I manually tried `...\` and it did not work. I need to go up one folder level. Only `../` has been doing the job so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. I looked at the wrong line.

```
 SET "location=%%c"
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  set "location=!location:~%%b!"
  set "back=../"
  ECHO(!back!!location!
```

does the job. `!location:~%%b!` deletes leading characters from the full absolute path up to the folder root, so I just have to add my string after this

Comment: (will accept the answer when stackoverflow lets me; says I have to wait 2 days)